# ASP.NET MVC - Implementing Search action jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, search

I've this scenario:

Site.Master

```
    ...               
    <%= Html.TextBox("ricerca") %>
    <img src="" alt ="" id="search" />
    ...

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#search').click(function() {
                var valueSearch = $('#ricerca').val();
                Search(valueSearch);
            });
        });
        function Search(valueSearch) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Search",
                data: "value=" + valueSearch
            });
        }
```

HomeController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string value)
    {
        //...logic search
        return View();
    }
```

When i click on image called correctly the Search action, but after "Return View();" don't load the Search view (positioned in the folder Home)

Why don't show?

Answer (score 1):

At no point are you inserting the data returned from the server into the document. That needs to happen within `$.ajax`'s [success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Search",
    data: "value=" + valueSearch,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("#someDiv").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean you want to replace the current loaded page with the search page via ajax?

Comment: exactly! i tried with Html.ActionLink, but i can't pass textbox value.